# What direction is current for an electron in both $E$ and $B$ fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electrons, electric-current

According to Fleming's left hand rule:

[image: Left hand rule]

I am a bit confused however in the case of an electron travelling in a region of both electric and magnetic fields, which direction would the electric current be?

I know that for a current carrying conductor, the current is opposite to electron flow, does that mean that in the case of a single electron the current would be in the opposite direction to the motion of the electron?

Comment: In your text you write "Fleming's *left* hand rule", but your image shows a *right* hand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what fields exist in space, electric current is always in the direction opposite to the direction of motion of e-, because e- are negatively charged particles.

However, current is not defined for a single e-, because current is a continuous flow of charges. But if we *have* to tell the direction of current anyways in case of a single e-, we would say it is in the opposite direction.

In the image attached, electric current means that if a positively charged particle is moving in that direction, B is in that direction, then Force will be in this direction.

If an e- is moving in the same direction as the positively charged particle was moving, then direction of force will rotate 180 degs

Comment: Not sure why you assume that electric current arises necessarily from electrons (what about ions? positrons? quasielectrons?).

Answer (score 0):

Fleming's right hand rule (as shown in your image)
is just a mnemonic for the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)
in the formula
$$F=I\vec{\ell}\times\vec{B}$$
where $\vec{F}$ is the magnetic force acting on a piece of wire,
$I$ is the current, $\vec{\ell}$ is the length
of the piece of wire, and $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field.

This magnetic force on a current-carrying wire
is actually a consequence of the Lorentz forces
acting on all the electrons moving within the wire.

The [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) on a single particle is
$$\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$$
where $q$ is the electric charge and $\vec{v}$
is the velocity of the particle.

Remember that an electron is negatively charged
(i.e. $q$ is negative) and therefore
its velocity is opposite to the direction of the current.

So therefore you can use the same right hand rule
for ($\vec{F}, q\vec{v}, \vec{B}$)
like you did for ($\vec{F}, I\vec{\ell}, \vec{B}$).